# Print a triangle of characters in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print a triangle of characters. I want it like this.

```
                      A
                     A B
                    A B C
                   A B C D
                  A B C D E
```

Below is my code.

```
public class Pro8Point3
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int space=29;
    char ch;
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      ch='A';  
      //Print spaces in decreasing order. A is at 29th position.
      for (int j=1; j<=space; j++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
      }
      //Print Triangle. 

      for (int k=1; k<=i; k++) {
        System.out.print(ch+" ");
        ch+=1;
      }
      space--;
      // System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();    
  }
}
```

But its not giving me desire output. Please guide me where did I make a mistake over here.

Comment: It would be easier if you also posted the current output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(" ");
```

should be

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

and you should uncomment this line at the bottom of the for loop:

```
System.out.println();
```

Final code, fixed up formatting and made the above changes:

```
public class Pro8Point3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int space=29;
        char ch;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            ch = 'A';  

            //Print spaces in decreasing order. A is at 29th position.
            for (int j = 1; j <= space; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Print Triangle.
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.print(ch + " ");
                ch+=1;
            }

            space--;

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
                             A
                            A B
                           A B C
                          A B C D
                         A B C D E
```

Answer (score 2):

after @smarx's correct answer, I wanted to post a general purpose method for such a requirement. It may look like this

```
public class Pro8Point3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(5, 20); 
    }

    private static void print(int level, int position) {

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {

            char c = 'A';

            for(int j = 1; j < level + position - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print(Character.valueOf(c++) + " ");

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```